# Understanding Django managers

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have the following model in one of my django app (cards) :

```
# cards/models.py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class CardManager(models.Manager):
    def insert_base_owned_cards(user):
        cards = Card.objects.filter(isBaseCard=True)
        for card in cards:
            OwnedCard(card=card, user=user).save()


class Card(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    cardSet = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    rarity = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Common')
    attack = models.IntegerField()
    health = models.IntegerField()
    cost = models.IntegerField()
    isBaseCard = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class OwnedCard(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    card = models.ForeignKey(Card, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.card.name
```

And I call the `CardManager` class like this in the users app model :

```
# users/models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from cards.models import CardManager

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # add additional fields in here
    credit = models.IntegerField(default=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def insertBaseCards(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        CardManager.insert_base_owned_cards(instance)
```

The code as is works, but I am pretty sure that I am not following the standards. From what I saw, I shouldn't call `CardManager.insert_base_owned_cards(arg)` but either `Card.objects.insert_base_owned_cards(arg)` or `OwnedCard.objects.insert_base_owned_cards(arg)` however since the method in the manager use both `Card` and `OwnedCard`, I am unsure as to how to do it.

One other thing that makes me think that I am not doing it right is that pylint is throwing the following error :

```
[E0213:Method should have "self" as first argument
```

on `def insert_base_owned_cards(user):`.

Please, let me know if I should add any code or informations

Python version : 3.6
Django version : 2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood the concept of managers. 
If you want to call manager by

```
Card.objects.insert_base_owned_cards(arg)
```

You have to override base manager in Card model, adding field:

```
objects = CardManager()
```

But it still is kinda wrong, because managers shouldn't be used for specific model operations. In managers you put methods like create or querysets. 
Your method

`def insert_base_owned_cards()`
should be in model not in manager

And about last question, add self to:

```
def insert_base_owned_cards(self, user):
```

I recommend you to read managers docs carefully, it is well explained there:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing the manager definition on the Card model.

To define this add

```
objects = CardManager()
```

This will override the base Manager object in place of your own but as you have inherited from models.Manager, you will still have access to the same methods.

You could define this as

```
mymanager = CardManager()
```

which would allow you to use either `Card.objects.insert_base_owned_cards(instance)` or `Card.mymanager.insert_base_owned_cards(instance)`

To then access the manager, you would call

```
`Card.objects.insert_base_owned_cards(instance)`
```

once you have added the `self` argument as below.

```
def insert_base_owned_cards(self, user):
```